# VB.Net Close workbook without closing all other Open workbooks

Tags: vb.net, excel

The task is as follows:

1. I want to open an Excel document from a VB.NET GUI, call it wb1
2. Then, I will call a VBA macro from wb1 using the VB.NET GUI
3. The VBA macro generates another workbook, wb2
4. I want to close wb1 (without saving), but leave wb2 open

The fourth step is what I'm having trouble with. I can call xlWb.close(), but this will close all the workbooks.

What I have so far:

```
Dim xlApp as new Excel.application
Dim xlWb as Excel.workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("File Path") 'this will open wb1
xlApp.Run("Wb1 Macro") 'this creates wb2

xlWb.close() 
xlApp.quit()
```

How can I specify which workbook I would like to close through VB.net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the problem is on this line:

```
xlApp.quit()
```

That will close the Excel instance, and therefore all the open workbooks (including the one opened by the Macro)